# How to identify which property in the formgroup emitted valuechanges event

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Below is the structure of the nested form group

```
   this.userProfileSettingsForm = fb.group({
      general: fb.group({
        language: [],
        theme: []
      }),
      report: fb.group({
        display: [],
        density: [],
      })
    })
```

If I subscribe to the general group like below, I am getting all property values with the updated one. But I want to get only the property which I updated in the form. **For Ex**: If I change the property **language** under **general** FormGroup, only I want to receive the language property updated value.

```
    this.userProfileSettingsForm.controls.general.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (value: any) => {
        console.log(value)
      }
    )
```

Can anyone tell me how can I identify the particular property changes by subscribing to the group?

Comment: @kasptom - I understand we can subscribe language property alone to get language control value. My group is quite large, I am trying to use one subscribe for the group and identify the changed property rather than sending all property to update .Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Each control in the group can subscribe to the changes event.

Comment: @John Peters - We cant identify the single property by subscribing to the group?

Comment: You can get formGroup.controls and filter for non pristine conditions.

Comment: @JohnPeters - Can you share me some sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a variable and store the nested formgroup in it. Like we make get functions to access form arrays.

Something like this below.

`let addressGroup = this.personalInfoForm.controls['address'] as FormGroup; addressGroup.controls['country'].valueChanges.subscribe(res => { this.getStates() })`